# BTRFS Mount Trapped in Snapper Rollback

Tags: opensuse, btrfs

I'm using snapper in openSUSE.

For learning purpose I did `% snapper rollback`. It was more like a curiosity reason about snapper, but become a blunder.

After `% snapper rollback`, my `% snapper list` become empty. It seems like root filesystem mounted to a snapshot volume as shown in command below.

```
% sudo snapper list
Type   | # | Pre # | Date | User | Cleanup | Description | Userdata
-------+---+-------+------+------+---------+-------------+---------
single | 0 |       |      | root |         | current     |     

% sudo snapper rollback
IO error (.snapshots is not a btrfs subvolume).

% mount | grep '/dev/sda8 on / type'
/dev/sda8 on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=400,subvol=/@/.snapshots/75/snapshot)
```

How do I solve the issue without altering `/etc/fstab`?

How do I undo the rollback to my normal filesystem?

How to use rollback properly?

Answer (score 2):

1. First I need to add this line to `/etc/fstab`

   ```
   % sudo nano /etc/fstab
   UUID=e901452a-b3ea-48d2-acdb-6687fad0be50 /.snapshots btrfs subvol=@/.snapshots   0 0
   ```

   and mount it, no need to reboot.

   ```
   % sudo mount /.snapshots
   ```
2. Get current snap

   In my case, previously I have snapshot number 75.

   ```
   % sudo btrfs subvolume show /

   @/.snapshots/45/snapshot
       Name:           snapshot
       UUID:           29d4436b-72d1-f14d-a9e9-f04b70c0ebe0
       Parent UUID:        efa9f21b-f3b7-3543-9649-3897e083b39d
       Received UUID:      -
       Creation time:      2018-01-03 00:15:01 +0700
       Subvolume ID:       355
       Generation:         5677
       Gen at creation:    3968
       Parent ID:      301
       Top level ID:       301
       Flags:          -
       Snapshot(s):
                   @/.snapshots/50/snapshot
                   @/.snapshots/51/snapshot
   ```

   and

   ```
   % sudo btrfs subvolume get-default /

   ID 355 gen 5682 top level 301 path @/.snapshots/45/snapshot
   ```
3. list snapper
       % sudo snapper list

   ```
   Type   | #  | Pre # | Date                            | User | Cleanup  | Description  | Userdata     
   -------+----+-------+---------------------------------+------+----------+--------------+--------------
   single | 0  |       |                                 | root |          | current      |              
   single | 3  |       | Mon 01 Jan 2018 02:45:03 PM WIB | root | timeline | timeline     |              
   single | 7  |       | Mon 01 Jan 2018 04:30:01 PM WIB | root | timeline | timeline     |              
   single | 40 |       | Tue 02 Jan 2018 10:15:01 PM WIB | root | timeline | timeline     |              
   single | 41 |       | Tue 02 Jan 2018 10:52:35 PM WIB | root |          | backup.epsi  |              
   pre    | 42 |       | Tue 02 Jan 2018 11:01:48 PM WIB | root | number   | zypp(zypper) | important=yes
   post   | 43 | 42    | Tue 02 Jan 2018 11:07:23 PM WIB | root | number   |              | important=yes
   single | 44 |       | Tue 02 Jan 2018 11:15:01 PM WIB | root | timeline | timeline     |              
   single | 45 |       | Wed 03 Jan 2018 12:15:01 AM WIB | root | timeline | timeline     |              
   pre    | 46 |       | Wed 03 Jan 2018 12:16:34 AM WIB | root | number   | zypp(zypper) | important=no 
   post   | 47 | 46    | Wed 03 Jan 2018 12:19:38 AM WIB | root | number   |              | important=no 
   pre    | 48 |       | Wed 03 Jan 2018 12:47:47 AM WIB | root | number   | zypp(zypper) | important=no 
   post   | 49 | 48    | Wed 03 Jan 2018 12:48:10 AM WIB | root | number   |              | important=no 
   ...
   ```

   I decide to go back to 45.
4. BTRFS ID

   ```
   % sudo btrfs subvolume list -a /

   ID 257 gen 4804 top level 5 path <FS_TREE>/@
   ID 258 gen 5096 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/opt
   ID 259 gen 4157 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/srv
   ID 260 gen 5672 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/tmp
   ID 261 gen 5538 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/usr/local
   ID 262 gen 5688 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/var/cache
   ID 263 gen 4157 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/var/crash
   ID 264 gen 4157 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/var/lib/libvirt/images
   ID 265 gen 4157 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/var/lib/machines
   ID 266 gen 4157 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/var/lib/mailman
   ID 267 gen 4157 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/var/lib/mariadb
   ID 268 gen 4157 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/var/lib/mysql
   ID 269 gen 4157 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/var/lib/named
   ID 270 gen 4157 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/var/lib/pgsql
   ID 271 gen 5688 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/var/log
   ID 272 gen 4157 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/var/opt
   ID 273 gen 5688 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/var/spool
   ID 274 gen 5672 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/var/tmp
   ID 301 gen 5674 top level 257 path <FS_TREE>/@/.snapshots
   ID 304 gen 3008 top level 301 path <FS_TREE>/@/.snapshots/3/snapshot
   ID 311 gen 3160 top level 301 path <FS_TREE>/@/.snapshots/7/snapshot
   ID 345 gen 3737 top level 301 path <FS_TREE>/@/.snapshots/40/snapshot
   ID 350 gen 3849 top level 301 path <FS_TREE>/@/.snapshots/41/snapshot
   ID 351 gen 3862 top level 301 path <FS_TREE>/@/.snapshots/42/snapshot
   ID 353 gen 3874 top level 301 path <FS_TREE>/@/.snapshots/43/snapshot
   ID 354 gen 3887 top level 301 path <FS_TREE>/@/.snapshots/44/snapshot
   ID 355 gen 5688 top level 301 path <FS_TREE>/@/.snapshots/45/snapshot
   ID 356 gen 3972 top level 301 path <FS_TREE>/@/.snapshots/46/snapshot
   ID 357 gen 3980 top level 301 path <FS_TREE>/@/.snapshots/47/snapshot
   ID 358 gen 4021 top level 301 path <FS_TREE>/@/.snapshots/48/snapshot
   ID 359 gen 4022 top level 301 path <FS_TREE>/@/.snapshots/49/snapshot
   ```

   I find the ID of 45, it is 355.
5. Change default

   To make it writable

   ```
   % sudo btrfs property set -ts /.snapshots/45/snapshot ro false
   ```

   And make it default

   ```
   % sudo btrfs subvolume set-default 355 /
   ```

   Then reboot
6. Remove the annoying rollback snapshot.

   ```
   % sudo snapper delete 75

   % sudo snapper delete 76

   % sudo snapper delete 77

   % sudo snapper list
   ```

That's all

Thank you